# How do you generate a random number within a given limit using the ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do you generate a random number within a given limit using the ActionScript?
Suppose the limit is 1-100. Can you Answer me the explanation too

I want to something put in the twitter or facebook, it wil just moves up n down (i.e moving the placing the object).. For that we need to generate the random numbers r8

Answer (score 10):

So if I understand well, you want something like a next(low, high) method. AS3 contains already a Math.random() method what generates a floating point random number from 0 to 1.

In order to restrict it, you need to do something like this:

```
var low:Number = 1;
var high:Number= 100;
var result:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + high - low)) + low;
```

The code is quite straightforward, basically you're multiplying the difference between high & low and adding the low. Overall result is floored using Math.floor() to be sure it's an integer.

Hope it helps!

Comment: one off? if Math.random() gives 1.0: 1.0 * (1 + 100 - 1) + 1 = 101.

Comment: No, I think it's correct. Math.random() generates a pseudo-random number n, where 0 <= n < 1. So it will never be 1.0, always a lower value that you floor afterwards anyway. From doc: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Math.html#random()

Answer (score 4):

To get a number from 0 to 100, you can use:

```
Math.random()*100;
```

To get a number from from 10 to 110 use:

```
Math.random()*100 + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone needs Kel answer wrapped in a Flex Random number generator for a range of values

```
    public function Random(min:int, max:int):int
    {
        var resp:int ;

        resp = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 + max - min)) + min;

        return resp ;               
    }
```